# How to use Min,max and average with Solr.net

Tags: lucene, solr, average, solrnet, min

I found http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Stats link.

But i cannot understand properly.

I want to use min,max kind of function with solr query.

My query(Display min, max and average price of Round shape and color D and clarity FL and caratweight.(This query will be genarated based on user's selection dynamically)

(Shape:"Round") AND (Color:"D") AND (Clarity:"FL") AND (CaratWeight:[1 TO 10])

But how can i use such kind of function and select specific column.

Now i am somewhat nearer...

By using following url, i am getting  min,max,count and mean..things those i want.
But its in xml format. Now i want to cusomize. I want to use this result in my asp.net code behind and want to do further computation.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/coreMikisa/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&stats=true&stats.field=Price
```

So please reply.. how can i get???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/coreMikisa/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&stats=true&stats.field=Price
```

This can be expressed in SolrNet as:

```
var statsParams = new StatsParameters();
statsParams.AddField("Price");
var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions {
    Rows = 10,
    Start = 0,
    Stats = statsParams
});
// use results.Stats...
```

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer, how can we use it to make average of a field in java using solrj and on solr gui?

Comment: @DivyangShah please create a new question.

Comment: I can't create new question.

Comment: Weird... then ask in the mailing list instead: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/