# How to use the XML result of SolrNet in my ASP.NET code behind

Tags: solrnet

I found http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Stats link. But I cannot understand it properly. I want to use a (min,max) kind of function with a [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) query.

My query (display min, max and average price of Round shape and color D and clarity FL and caratweight. (This query will be generated based on user's selection dynamically.)

```
(Shape:"Round") AND (Color:"D") AND (Clarity:"FL") AND (CaratWeight:[1 TO 10])
```

But how can I use such kind of function and select specific column?

Now I am somewhat nearer...

By using the following URL, I am getting min, max, count and mean.. Things like those I want. But it's in XML format. Now I want to customize. I want to use this result in my ASP.NET code behind and want to do further computation.

http://localhost:8983/solr/coreMikisa/select/?q=%3A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&stats=true&stats.field=Price

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Min,max and average with Solr.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609870/how-to-use-min-max-and-average-with-solr-net)

Answer (score 0):

Load the XML result into XML document and use XPath to access get the value of desired elements.

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(solrXmlResult);
var mean = double.Parse(xmlDocument.DocumentElement.GetElementByTagName("//mean")[0].InnerText);
...
```

or based on your XML

```
var mean = double.Parse(
  xmlDocument.DocumentElement.GetElementByTagName(
    "//lst[@name=\"tag\"]/double[@name=\"min\"]"
  )[0].InnerText);
```

Comment: My xml have lac of records and in last <lst name="stats">
−
<lst name="stats_fields">
−
<lst name="Price">
<double name="min">10.0</double>
<double name="max">2999850.0</double>
<double name="sum">4.4995650105E11</double>
<long name="count">299985</long>
<long name="missing">0</long>
<double name="sumOfSquares">8.9986950630438234E17</double>
<double name="mean">1499930.0</double>
<double name="stddev">865983.545887726</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst> tag and i want value of min.. is this possible??

Comment: put this XML do your answer, please. what is "lac"?

Comment: Then XPath expression "//lst[@name=\"stats"]/lst[@name=\"tag\"]/double[@name=\"min\"]" should work. Learn more about XPath.